# Read all files and subfolders in it

Tags: php

Can anyone guide me to complete : This function usually reads the entire folder architecture. and display as an array, but subfolders also creating array. but i dont need array for each subfolder just i need path. can anyone guide me.

```
 function dirToArray($dir) { 
  $result = array();
 //$result1 = array(); 
 $dummy = array();
 $cdir = scandir($dir); 
foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) 
 { 
  if (!in_array($value,array(".",".."))) 
  { 

    if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)) 
     { 

        $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value); 
     } 
     else 
     { 
        $result[] = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value; 
     } 
  } 
 } 
 return $result; 
}
```

Above function working fine, but small modification needed in this function.

```
$dir = "test";
echo "<pre>";
print_r(dirToArray($dir));
```

Output :

```
    Array
    (
[admin] => Array
    (
        [0] => test\admin\asdf1.txt
    )

[app] => Array
    (
        [0] => test\app\asdf1.txt
        [1] => test\app\two.txt
    )

[0] => test\asdf1.txt
  )
```

Expected output is :

```
  Array
  (
[0] => test\admin\asdf1.txt
[1] => test\app\asdf1.txt
[2] => test\app\two.txt
[3] => test\asdf1.txt
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the array. According to [this site](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php), you can use the following function to flatten it down:

```
function arrayFlatten($array) { 
    $flattern = array(); 
    foreach ($array as $key => $value){ 
        $new_key = array_keys($value); 
        $flattern[] = $value[$new_key[0]]; 
    } 
    return $flattern; 
} 

$flattened = arrayFlatten( $dir );
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick update. i added this code foreach(dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value) as $path){
           $result[] = $path;  
          }  to get desired format. my goal to archive entire project and moving to other folder. Hopefuly it is done.

Comment: You can do that, but remember, it won't work. You need to `push` it. Try `array_push( $result, $path );`